# Use unicode as predicate in xpath with lxml and python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, unicode, lxml

I've been facing the problem where I have an XML file with Unicode strings and need to evaluate an Xpath on it, through lxml in Python-2.7.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import etree
...
class Language:

description = None

def __init__(self, description):
   xpath = "//language[./description = '{}']//description/text()".format(description)
   self.description= lang_xml.xpath(xpath)
   ...


lang = Language(u"Norwegian Bokmål")
```

Gives error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe5' in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop mixing them.

```
xpath = u"//language[./description = '{}']//description/text()".format(description)
```